# Parsing date with time.Parse

Tags: go

Hi I am trying to parse date in the format YYYY-MM-DD. I am trying this:

```
time.Parse("2020-12-30", "2016-01-01")
```

but I get the error, which I guess is a parsing error,

> 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC parsing time "2016-01-01" as
>   "2020-12-30": cannot parse "-01-01" as "0-"

How do I parse this, maybe give some hints through additional examples? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) uses a reference time of `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006` as its format:

```
time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2016-01-01")
```

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/34XaXjHF7hy.